# How to reload modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am opening a modal on a click function. Within the modal I then click a "new account" button, and click outside the modal, but the page does not reload, and then click other account to open modal so new account button disabled.

How can I make the page reload when I click outside the modal?

Comment: What have you done so far? We are here to help, not to do your work

Comment: how set modal refresh. then click on modal. and click outside the modal. modal close and not refresh the page...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  location.reload();
})
```